# How to implement support for "web user sessions" in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, session, web-applications, usersession, webbroker

In Web Applications, the access to *"web user session"* information is very important, and from "Delphi 6" to "Delphi XE5", Delphi included the **WebSnap** library which has a component named **SessionService** to support the manage of "web user session" information.

**Since Delphi no longer have WebSnap** (removed in XE6), I don't know how to implement support for *"web user session"* in WebBroker Applications with Delphi.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

With [xxm](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm) I use a local object collection of session objects and keep a reference in a threadvar while building a response to the request ([see here](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/demo2/02%20Session/xxmSession.pas)) but some HTTP platforms like IIS and Apache now use separate processes to handle incoming requests, so to support that I would either store it all in database, perhaps even a local [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) database file, or use a specific COM server service that serves session objects (which in its turn will handle storing and loading data and session expiry).